# How to use format js in rails 7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, stripe-payments

I'm using gem stripe in rails 7 and I'd like to access the checkout page to make the payments or cancel the order, however, since it is rails 7 (and does not have a webpacker and nothing related to javascripts) it does not want to recognize the js format at the time of the request

- My checkout_controller.rb

  ```
   class CheckoutController < ApplicationController
      def create
        @session = Stripe::Checkout::Session.create({
        success_url: root_url,
        cancel_url: root_url,
        payment_method_types: ['card'],
        line_items: [
          { price: 'price_1JLaadjkjcanlsr', quantity: 1 },
        ],
        mode: 'payment',
       })

      # here is my problem, not working
      respond_to do |format|
         format.js
       end
     end
   end
  ```
- This is the code in case it recognizes the format.js in the request /chekout/create.js.erb

  ```
     var stripe = Stripe("<%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:public_key) %>");

     stripe.redirectToCheckout({ 
       sessionId: '<%= @session.id %>' 
     }).then(function (result) { 
       console.log(result.error.message); });
  ```
- routes

  ```
    post "checkout/create", to: "checkout#create", as: "checkout_create"
  ```
- Link to access the stripe payment method

  ```
   <%= button_to 'Checkout', checkout_create_path, method: :post, remote: true %>
  ```
- My stripe script in application.html.erb

  ```
   <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
   <%= stylesheet_link_tag "inter-font", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
  ```

The error that I get it

```
# ActionController::UnknownFormat Extracted source (around line #21):
         
     })

     respond_to do |format|
        format.js
     end
   end
```

If anyone has been able to work on rails 7 with format js in requests and could help me I'd be very grateful

Comment: Why do you have to do the redirect from javascript? Doesn't Stripe have a Ruby SDK? Using a js.erb template just to do a redirect is pretty insane - its like mowing your lawn with a outboard motor.

Comment: Well you did used to have to redirect from Javascript, but Stripe changed that recently. @Samuel, you don't really need that JS, you can just take `@session.url` and redirect to it. https://github.com/stripe-samples/checkout-one-time-payments/blob/master/server/ruby/server.rb#L70-L82

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class CheckoutController < ApplicationController
def create
  @session = Stripe::Checkout::Session.create({
  success_url: root_url,
  cancel_url: root_url,
  payment_method_types: ['card'],
  line_items: [
    { price: 'price_1JLaadjkjcanlsr', quantity: 1 },
  ],
  mode: 'payment',
 })

# Try do this! Hope this work for you
  redirect_to @session.url, allow_other_host: true
 end
```

When you use the Stripe Checkout you need to redirect to the Stripe Site to complete the transaction. [Here is a youtube link where explain how to set up in Rails 7](https://youtu.be/ji_rNMTaF9g) and [I found the solution here](https://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/s8qhwx/launching_a_new_comprehensive_stripe_on_rails/) -  Hope it works for you